# Why can't use a inside pointer to initialize two difference shared_ptr?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

class Base;

class Base {
public:
    int i;
    int j;
    Base(int _i, int _j) : i(_i), j(_j) {};
};

int main(void) {
    Base* q = new Base(5, 9);
    cout << q->i << endl;
    shared_ptr<Base> p(q);
    cout << p->j << endl;
    shared_ptr<Base> t(q);            // mark
    cout << p.use_count() << endl;
    // cout << t.use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After I run it on visual studio 2022 with C++11, the reference count is 1 rather than two, and there's something wrong with delete that makes the programme failed.

However, when I change the code marked into "shared_ptr t(p)", everything goes well.

How?

Comment: do you expect for variable `t` somehow know about existence of variable `p` and thus use the same counter for both variables?

Comment: This is why you should use `make_shared` instead of calling `new` directly to create shared pointers.  That way you only get one control block, and if you ever need to get a shared_ptr from a raw pointer, use `get_shared_from_this`.  Never construct a shared pointer from a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shared_ptr<Base> p(q);
shared_ptr<Base> t(q);
```

`p` and `t` now both have sole ownership of `*q` instead of sharing the ownership.

`p` and `t` do **not** share control blocks for `*q`. Whenever `p`or `t` reaches a reference count of zero, `*q` will be destructed - and the other `shared_ptr` will be left with a dangling reference.

Any references to the former object after its destruction results in undefined behavior.

---

> Why can't use a inside pointer to initialize two difference `shared_ptr`?

Because C++ relies on *you* to do it properly - but it doesn't do much to prevent you from violating the rules.

Comment: might be clearer to say "sole ownership" in the first sentence to make it clearer -- the `std::shared_ptr<T>(T *)` constructor expects a pointer to an unowned object and takes ownership of it with a reference count of 1.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Good point. I updated i a bit. Thanks.